# Getting an array of hash values given specific keys

Tags: ruby, hash

Given certain keys, I want to get an array of values from a hash (in the order I gave the keys). I had done this:

```
class Hash

  def values_for_keys(*keys_requested)
    result = []
    keys_requested.each do |key|
      result << self[key]
    end
    return result
  end

end
```

I modified the `Hash` class because I do plan to use it almost everywhere in my code.

But I don't really like the idea of modifying a core class. Is there a builtin solution instead? (couldn't find any, so I had to write this).

Comment: you could also write a utility class where ur function will take hash and keys as params.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use [`values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-values_at):

> **values_at(key, ...) → array**
>
> Return an array containing the values associated with the given keys. Also see `Hash.select`.
>
> ```
> h = { "cat" => "feline", "dog" => "canine", "cow" => "bovine" }
> h.values_at("cow", "cat")  #=> ["bovine", "feline"]
> ```

The documentation doesn't specifically say anything about the order of the returned array but:

1. The example implies that the array will match the `key` order.
2. The standard implementation does things in the right order.
3. There's no other sensible way for the method to behave.

For example:

```
>> h = { :a => 'a', :b => 'b', :c => 'c' }
=> {:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c"}
>> h.values_at(:c, :a)
=> ["c", "a"]
```

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you do this:

`your_hash.select{|key,value| given_keys.include?(key)}.values`